# Interrupted Bubble Sort Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not sure why my solution to the interrupted bubble sort question on codeeval is incorrect. The error message I got was "CodeEval Error: Process was aborted after 10 seconds". Can someone please help me out? I coded my solution in eclipse, tested it before submitting my solution on codeeval. Everything ran fine in eclipse. If someone could clue me in on what I did wrong so that I can learn from it, that would be great. Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
try
{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(System.in));          
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the test file: ");
        String testFile = reader.readLine(); //"src/testfile.txt";
        List<Sentence> infoArrayList = readStringFromFile(testFile);
        for (Sentence test: infoArrayList)
        {
            test.bubbleSort();
            test.printList();
        }   
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static List<Sentence> readStringFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
    List<Sentence> list = new ArrayList<Sentence>();
    String line; 
    Sentence intSentence;

    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
    {
        intSentence = new Sentence();
        if (!line.isEmpty())
        {
            String[] temp = line.split(" ");
            for (String s: temp)
            {
                if (!s.equals("|"))
                    intSentence.addLongToList(Long.parseLong((s)));
            }
            list.add(intSentence);
        }   
    }
    buffer.close();
    return list;
}
```

}

class Sentence {

```
private ArrayList<Long> sentenceList;

public Sentence()
{
    sentenceList = new ArrayList<Long>();
}

public void addLongToList (Long element)
{
    sentenceList.add(element); 
}

public void bubbleSort()
{
    Long num1;
    Long num2;
    Long iteration = sentenceList.remove(sentenceList.size()-1);

    for (int turn=0; turn<iteration; turn++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<sentenceList.size(); i++)
        {

            if ((i+1)<sentenceList.size())
            {
                num1 = sentenceList.get(i);
                num2 = sentenceList.get(i+1);
                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    sentenceList.set(i, num2);
                    sentenceList.set(i+1, num1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void printList()
{
    for (Long num: sentenceList)
    {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Testfile:

36 47 78 28 20 79 87 16 8 45 72 69 81 66 60 8 3 86 1000000000000 90 | 1
40 69 52 42 24 16 66 | 2
54 46 0 34 15 48 47 53 25 18 50 5 21 76 62 48 74 1 43 74 78 29 | 6
48 51 5 61 18 | 2
59 68 55 31 73 4 1 25 26 19 60 0 | 2

Answer (score 0):

In the Main class, the static method readStringFromFile is outside the ending Main class brace.  Place it inside the class and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for relying to my question. The static method readStringFromFile is inside the Main class. The formatting of my code looked off on stackoverflow page after I copied and pasted it from eclipse to the stackoverflow page.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            String parts[] = line.split(" \\| ");
            long iterations = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(String s : parts[0].split(" ")) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }

            for(long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                boolean madeChange = false;
                for(int x = 0; x < list.size() - 1; x++) {
                    if(x != 0 && list.get(x) < list.get(x - 1)) {
                        Collections.swap(list, x, x - 1);
                        madeChange = true;
                    } else if(list.get(x) > list.get(x + 1)) {
                        Collections.swap(list, x, x + 1);
                        madeChange = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!madeChange)
                    break;
            }

            boolean first = true;
            for(int num : list) {
                System.out.print((first ? "" : " ") + num);
                first = false;
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

        buffer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post both code and some text. Very awkward system.
-
Example: 1 3 2 4 | 1000000000000
This clearly does not need to be ran 1trillion times, but the program is asking that, does that mean we should do it? No, we know it only needs to be ran TWICE. (Well once, but twice to check it is actually finished sorting.)

Comment: As you see it only needed to iterate twice, once to fix it and a second to check it had been completely sorted.. no need to check it the other .9trillion times, so break the loop and move on to the next sequence.
    
Here is how I done it, please don't use this code:

Comment: Also note instead of the Boolean you may use Labels, but CodeEval does not support usage of Labels.